# htmlParse - inner text

Tags: html, r, parsing, rvest

I need to scrape this text:  from an html document using htmlParse (package: XML) in R:

```
<h1 class="IT">
<span class="f" id="hotel">HOTEL</span>
<span class="nowrap">
<i class="b stars ratings_stars_5  star_track"  data-track-on-mouseover=""></i>
</span>
</span>
</h1>
```

I am using this code (code-example) to scrape the name of hotels. However, I need to add the rating of the hotels:

```
for (i in seq_len(3)){

  txt <- getURL(url=baseURL[i], followlocation = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
  doc <- htmlParse(txt)

  hotel <- cssApply(doc, ".details>h3", cssCharacter)
  hotel <- cssApplyInNodeSet(doc, ".details", "h3", cssCharacter)
  data <- cbind(hotel)
}
```

Comment: any chance you could post the actual URL you're hitting? context might matter.

Comment: For instance, URL: http://www.booking.com/hotel/es/starwoodalfonso.es.html#tab-reviews    I have simplified the proposed code above.

Comment: The terms & conditions of that site say that scraping (and similar activities) are not allowed for commercial purposes. There is real legal liability for anyone who provides you an answer if you are planning on using this for anything but personal or academic use.

Comment: It is exclusively for academic use -a research about tourism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rvest` can generally make these ops much easier:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pg <- html("http://www.booking.com/hotel/es/starwoodalfonso.es.html#tab-reviews")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("i.b-sprite.stars") %>% 
  html_attr("class") %>% 
  str_extract("ratings_stars_[[:digit:]]+") %>% 
  str_replace("ratings_stars_", "") %>% 
  as.numeric()

## [1] 5

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("span#hp_hotel_name") %>% 
  html_text()

## [1] "Hotel Alfonso XIII"
```

should be very straightforward to stick results in a `data.frame`, wrap the iteration in an `lapply` then `dplyr::bind_rows`

**EDIT**

Since you're stuck with the `CSS` package you can use `rvest` + the `cssApply` in the exact same manner:

```
pg <- html("http://www.booking.com/hotel/es/starwoodalfonso.es.html#tab-reviews")

pg %>% 
  cssApply("i.b-sprite.stars", cssClass) %>% 
  str_extract("ratings_stars_[[:digit:]]+") %>% 
  str_replace("ratings_stars_", "") %>% 
  as.numeric()

pg %>% cssApply("span#hp_hotel_name", cssCharacter)
```

Comment: Thanks! I designed my full code using package CSS; could you suggest how I can scrape the class? cssClass? I am novice using R.